# Writing a vim function with string printing and concatenation

Tags: vimrc

I am trying to write my (first) function which is (eventually to be) a toggle on my colorscheme. What I have now is as follows:

```
nnoremap <expr> <leader>3 ToggleColors()
func ToggleColors()
    let x = ":colorscheme"
    echom '111' + x
    x = x += "TextMate"
    echom '222' + x
    return x
endfunc
```

Here is what I am trying to do:

- Set a variable `x` to be the string `:colorscheme`
- Print it, which should give me the output message `111 :colorscheme`
- Append to the variable `x`, so now it should be `:colorscheme TextMate`
- Print it again, so now it should print `222: colorscheme`

However, it seems like the `echom '111' + x` only prints `111`, and the string-concatenation is giving me an error.

What would be the proper way to write this? Finally, is there any way to debug functions in vim? Or do you just have to check `messages`? All the error messages (stacktraces) I get give almost zero information...less than even SQL would.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String concatination in Vim is done with a `.` (dot).

So:

```
func ToggleColor()
    let x = ":colorscheme"
    echom '111' . x
    let x .= " TextMate"
    echom '222' . x
    return x
endfunc
```

In your scenario I would *not* use map-expression. (Guess you want to use a function, because you are learning Vim)

```
nnoremap <leader>3 :call ToggleColors()<cr>
function ToggleColors()
    let x = "colorscheme"
    let x .= " TextMate"
    call execute(x)
endfunction
```

And the simplest solution would be:

```
nnoremap <leader>3 :colorscheme TextMate<cr>
```

---

When to use a map-expression?

Normally a mapping is fixed. Like

```
nnoremap A  B
```

So whenever you type `A` you will get `B`.

With a map-expression you are able to create a dynamic mapping.

This (useless) mapping maps `A` to either `0` or `$`.

```
:nnoremap <expr> A col('.') == 1?'$':'0'
```

If you hit `A` and the cursor is in the first column, you will jump to end of line. In all other scenarios the cursor jumps to the first column.

Instead of doing it on one line, you could also do it in a function:

```
nnoremap <expr> A  JumpAround()
function JumpAround()
    if col('.') == 1
        return '$'
    else
        return '0'
    endif
endfunction
```

Note that there are limitations what you can do in a function called from a map-expression. See `:h map-expression`.

Comment: thanks for this. A few questions: (1) are you able to do `func ()` without a function name, or that's just for an example? (2) why do you call `execute` at the end instead of `return`?

Comment: Finally, (3) `In your scenario I would not use map-expression` -- why would you use the `:call` over using the `<expr>`? When would you ever want to use `<expr>` then?

Comment: @David542 (1) Typo - fixed  (2) The `execute` just executes the string content. (3) see update